# How to change ajax url and data for post method for already initialized datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I see datatable must be initialized one time on page load.
The issue here I want to change ajax source and data to send to servr.
I do not know how to change these parameters. when I try , I get warning that I cannot reinitialize existing datatable object.
Data to send to server are different according to other options choice by user.
the guys here did not find the right solution. I have the same issue.
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/44395/how-do-i-change-the-ajax-parameters
How to deal with this?

Comment: Actually you **can** reinitialize your jQuery DataTable more than once if you use the **[destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy)** attribute

Comment: please provide the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function changeAjaxUrl(){
var table = $('#dtexample').DataTable();
table.ajax.url('newajaxurl' ).load();
}
```